# How to re-install deb package from MobileTerminal (iOS) [jailbroken]

Tags: terminal, bash, jailbreak, package-management

I am trying to run a command to re-install an already installed package. Here is what I see that gives me a clue that I am on the right path, but it doesn't install the package:

```
su
******
apt-get --reinstall kr.iolate.simulatetouch
```

The system gives me an error, for which I presume because the .deb file isn't found? How do I tell terminal to download it, if I must? And from where? Here is the complete input/output:

​

```
AlarmNextGen:~ mobile$ su
Password:
AlarmNextGen:/var/mobile root# apt-get --reinstall in
stall kr.iolate.simulatetouch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of kr.iolate.simulatetouch is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
AlarmNextGen:/var/mobile root#
```

I am doing this from command line for a few reasons. Once I get the command to run, I will compile it into a script to do this with activator. The main reason for doing this is because this package ceases to work after the device is rebooted, and must be re-installed over again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my suggestion solve your problem? If it did, could you please mark it as the correct answer? If it didn't, I could investigate further and provide a better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Download http://apt.thebigboss.org/repofiles/cydia/debs2.0/simulatetouch_0.7-17.deb to your device and then run this command:

`dpkg -i simulatetouch_0.7-17.deb`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Cydia packages via Safari or a computer. Anything can go wrong insider Terminal and it's not recommended unless you're an expert. For Safari, just find the direct link and unzip it through tweak like iFile. If you have a computer, just download the .deb file and then install it through iFunbox. Much easier and safer.

Source: [How to download Cydia .deb files on Windows & Mac](http://ihacksblog.com/download-cydia-deb-files-computer/)

Comment: iFile literally runs the same command that I told him to run, plus, he *specifically* asked for a command line solution.